# Can i convert from a list of chars to a string or term in Prolog

Tags: string, io, prolog, dcg

i use

```
read_line_to_codes(Stream,Line)
```

to read a line from a file .. first 
is there any way to read a line and assign it to a term in prolog ?? if not i managed to read a line and put it in this char list .. now this char list contains spaces .. which is bad .. so i want to convert it to a term or a string in prolog so that i can process it easier .. spaces cannot be atoms so thats a problem ..

i appreciate the help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input consists of Prolog terms, use read/1. You can convert character codes to an atom with atom_codes/2. A space, ' ', is also an atom, you can see that with the query: ?- atom(' '). A good way to read other input from a file with SWI-Prolog is to describe it with a DCG and then to use phrase_from_file/2 from library(pio).

Comment: Thanks alot .. ive managed to fix the reading bug .. but i still have one .. i have posted a new question id appreciate if u can give me some heads up on that one .. thanks alot